# Massive performance degradation on sustained sequential write

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, io

I'm in the process of migrating data into LUKS partitions.  Now that the operating system drive is running off LUKS, I tried to start migrating the data drives.  Then the server stopped responding.

This LUKS device was opened:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc data1
```

And either of these commands strangled the server:

```
pv /dev/zero > /dev/mapper/data1
pv /dev/zero > /dev/sdc
```

Not immediately, but within seconds, the server became unusably slow.  Everything blocked on I/O:

```
root@node51 [~]# ps aux | awk '{if($8~"D"||$8=="STAT"){print $0}}' 
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1197  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    06:39   0:00 [jbd2/dm-1-8]
root      1687  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        D    11:15   0:12 [kworker/u96:5]
root     13057  2.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    13:10   0:01 [dmcrypt_write]
root     13644 10.9  0.0   7452   784 pts/1    D+   13:10   0:08 pv /dev/zero
root     14159  0.0  0.0  98256  6836 ?        DNs  13:10   0:00 sshd: root [priv]
root     14772  0.0  0.0  29008    92 ?        D    13:11   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
root     14773  0.0  0.0  98256  6748 ?        DNs  13:11   0:00 sshd: root [priv]
root     15411  0.0  0.0  98256  6876 ?        DNs  13:11   0:00 sshd: root [priv]
root     16009  0.1  0.0  98256  6840 ?        DNs  13:11   0:00 sshd: root [priv]
root     16632  0.5  0.0  98256  6892 ?        DNs  13:11   0:00 sshd: root [priv]
root     16900  0.0  0.0   5448   356 pts/3    D+   13:11   0:00 awk {if($8~"D"||$8=="STAT"){print $0}}
root     28553  0.6  0.0      0     0 ?        D    12:12   0:21 [txg_sync]
```

Of note, for about two seconds, `pv` reported that it was copying data at more than `2GiB/s`.  This is both the write-back cache and the dirty pages filling up (found by monitoring `/proc/meminfo`).

Afterwards, `pv` recorded a normal `200MiB/s` write speed, but it was still ahead by between `2GiB` and `3GiB` in the write-back cache.

The server load average jumped up past 10.00 because of all the I/O blocking going on.

It takes a while to abort the `pv` write test because the write-back cache needs to be emptied, but right after the test was aborted, server performance returned to normal.

Interestingly, these commands don't cause the server to lag:

```
# Reads from dm-crypt block device
pv /dev/mapper/data1 > /dev/zero
# Reads from the raw block device
pv /dev/sdc > /dev/zero

# Writes to a control disk of a different model
pv /dev/zero > /dev/sdi
# Reads from a control disk
pv /dev/sdi > /dev/zero

# Writes to a file on a dm-crypt ext4 filesystem on a solid-state drive
pv /dev/zero > /tmp/empty
# Reads from that same solid-state drive
pv /dev/sda > /dev/zero
```

I have these questions:

1. **Why do sustained sequential writes to this data disk slow down the server so much?**
2. **How can I avoid bogging down the other disks when writing to a specific one or few?**
3. **Why is this kind of hard drive causing performance issues, but other drives don't?**

I have six disks of the same model (`/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd`, `/dev/sde`, `/dev/sdf`, `/dev/sdg`, and `/dev/sdh`) to encrypt and they will have sequential write workloads in the future, so I don't want the server to stall from this problem.

---

### Additional Information

#### Quick Facts

**Server:** [Dell PowerEdge T320](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20150929194142/http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-t320/pd)

**Kernel:** `Linux node51 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Operating system:** [Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus 64-bit](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160422042026/https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes)

**Problematic hard drive:** [Toshiba PH3500U-1I72](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20150724162610/http://www.amazon.com/Toshiba-7200rpm-3-5-Inch-Internal-PH3500U-1I72/dp/B00OP2PKH2)

*I have six of these disks, all known to be healthy, and I tested two of them and experienced a server-wide I/O performance drop with both.  They read and write at `200MiB/s` near the beginning.*

**Control (problem-free) hard drive:** [Samsung SP1614C](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160326091000/http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/samsung-80gpp/index2.html)

*This disk has a sustained write speed of `50MiB/s`.  Could it be that the problematic disk is too fast?*

**Disk controller:** [Dell PERC H310](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20150218185246/http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/dell-perc-h310-spec-sheet.pdf)

*Two solid-state drives and six problematic hard drives are connected to this controller, all of which are passed directly as AHCI.  The control disk is connected to a SATA port built into the motherboard.*

#### I/O schedulers

```
root@node51 [/tmp]# tail -n +1 /sys/block/sd*/queue/scheduler 
==> /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler <==
noop [deadline] cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler <==
noop [deadline] cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdc/queue/scheduler <==
[noop] deadline cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdd/queue/scheduler <==
[noop] deadline cfq 

==> /sys/block/sde/queue/scheduler <==
[noop] deadline cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdf/queue/scheduler <==
[noop] deadline cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdg/queue/scheduler <==
[noop] deadline cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdh/queue/scheduler <==
[noop] deadline cfq 

==> /sys/block/sdi/queue/scheduler <==
noop [deadline] cfq
```

*Changing the scheduler of `/dev/sdc` from `noop` to `deadline` makes no perceptible difference.  Changing the scheduler to `cfq` seemed to reduce the delay somewhat, but I/O operations on the other disks still suffered.*

#### `vm.dirty*` kernel parameters

```
root@node51 [~]# sysctl -a | grep 'vm.dirty'
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200
```

#### Examples of slowness detected and logged to `/var/log/syslog`

ZFS transaction group sync:

```
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.179688] INFO: task txg_sync:3179 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.179905]       Tainted: P           O    4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180110] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180357] txg_sync        D ffff88060b68baa8     0  3179      2 0x00000000
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180362]  ffff88060b68baa8 ffff880616a96d00 ffff8806133ea940 ffff880603dc2940
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180366]  ffff88060b68c000 ffff880616ad6d00 7fffffffffffffff ffff88056cb8c508
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180368]  0000000000000001 ffff88060b68bac0 ffffffff818211f5 0000000000000000
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180372] Call Trace:
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180381]  [<ffffffff818211f5>] schedule+0x35/0x80
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180385]  [<ffffffff81824315>] schedule_timeout+0x1b5/0x270
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180390]  [<ffffffff810abe52>] ? default_wake_function+0x12/0x20
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180395]  [<ffffffff810c33b2>] ? __wake_up_common+0x52/0x90
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180398]  [<ffffffff81820744>] io_schedule_timeout+0xa4/0x110
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180412]  [<ffffffffc05afbec>] cv_wait_common+0xbc/0x140 [spl]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180416]  [<ffffffff810c3a70>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180423]  [<ffffffffc05afcc8>] __cv_wait_io+0x18/0x20 [spl]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180487]  [<ffffffffc071320e>] zio_wait+0x10e/0x1f0 [zfs]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180528]  [<ffffffffc069ce66>] dsl_pool_sync+0x2c6/0x430 [zfs]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180573]  [<ffffffffc06b85b6>] spa_sync+0x366/0xb30 [zfs]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180576]  [<ffffffff810abe52>] ? default_wake_function+0x12/0x20
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180623]  [<ffffffffc06c9a4a>] txg_sync_thread+0x3ba/0x630 [zfs]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180669]  [<ffffffffc06c9690>] ? txg_delay+0x180/0x180 [zfs]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180676]  [<ffffffffc05aae31>] thread_generic_wrapper+0x71/0x80 [spl]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180682]  [<ffffffffc05aadc0>] ? __thread_exit+0x20/0x20 [spl]
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180686]  [<ffffffff810a0588>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180688]  [<ffffffff810a04b0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180692]  [<ffffffff8182568f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 11 19:28:44 node51 kernel: [ 4080.180694]  [<ffffffff810a04b0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
```

ext4 journal:

```
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.186474] INFO: task jbd2/dm-2-8:1148 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.193164]       Tainted: P           O    4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.199950] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208323] jbd2/dm-2-8     D ffff88060a6e7c98     0  1148      2 0x00000000
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208330]  ffff88060a6e7c98 0000000000000246 ffff8806133eb700 ffff88060b561b80
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208333]  ffff88060a6e8000 ffff88060aeb68b8 ffff88060a6e7d88 ffff88060a6e7d70
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208336]  ffff88060b561b80 ffff88060a6e7cb0 ffffffff818211f5 ffff8805fd6af900
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208339] Call Trace:
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208355]  [<ffffffff818211f5>] schedule+0x35/0x80
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208361]  [<ffffffff812ea0e0>] jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x240/0x1870
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208365]  [<ffffffff810b6be1>] ? dequeue_entity+0x431/0xa80
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208368]  [<ffffffff810b774a>] ? dequeue_task_fair+0x51a/0x8a0
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208372]  [<ffffffff810c3a70>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208378]  [<ffffffff810ec5fe>] ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x5e/0x90
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208381]  [<ffffffff812ef32a>] kjournald2+0xca/0x250
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208384]  [<ffffffff810c3a70>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x60/0x60
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208387]  [<ffffffff812ef260>] ? commit_timeout+0x10/0x10
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208391]  [<ffffffff810a0588>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208394]  [<ffffffff810a04b0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208397]  [<ffffffff8182568f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6000.208399]  [<ffffffff810a04b0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
May 11 20:46:46 node51 kernel: [ 6292.776357] perf interrupt took too long (2539 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Comment: May I ask what type of performance you'd expect from this setup?

Comment: @ewwhite: If I type in `uptime` and press [Enter], I should expect to see the load averages in less than `0m0.010s`, not after `6m49.891s`.  (Yes, that is an actual result from `time`.)

Comment: Considering you are using a decent PERC, perhaps try disabling OS write cache

Comment: This discusses an issue where the os write cache is so large, when the system flushes it, the system grinds to a halt. Where as, if you make it smaller, it is only the application that will grind.
http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/Disabling-in-memory-write-cache-for-x86-64-in-Linux-II-td742553.html

Comment: @Patrick: Disabling the write cache (`sysctl vm.dirty_background_ratio=0` and `sysctl vm.dirty_ratio=0`) eliminated the OS freezing as a side effect of reducing I/O throughput by a factor of 165. I tried playing with the ratios, but the whole server I/O still crumples at the hard drive's `200MiB/s` sustained write.

Comment: Yes, try small ratios or set dirty_bytes directly. dirty_background_bytes is when to begin async flushing, dirty_bytes is when to lock up and go synch. Try as low as 16. Double check settings took hold. Sorry thats all i've got :)  LUKS would be the next culprit? Keep in mind, PV is not 'realworld' usage.

Comment: @Patrick: I initially suspected LUKS (specifically, the `dmcrypt_write` kernel process), but it wasn't bottlenecking, and the running kernel wasn't affected by known issues such as [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203762). The server should not buckle from erasing a hard drive with `pv`. (ATA Secure Erase is not available for other reasons.) I've wiped all sorts of drives with `pv` before, but the other computers and drives chugged along just fine.

Comment: Ok. "problem free control disk is conected to the motherboard" - So, the disk that won't flush is on the PERC, and the disk you are wiping is on the PERC. Perhaps the PERC is locking up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39713/discussion-between-deltik-and-patrick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The control disk is connected to a SATA port built into the
>   motherboard.

As stated, the disks experiencing the journal flush time out issues are connected to the PERC, the same controller that the 'problematic' Toshiba's are connected to.

The PERC 310 is only a basic hardware raid card. It's CPU is probably easily overwhelmed, either that or there is a firmware bug. Direct AHCI is not a very common usage.

I would suggest the IO is locking up on the PERC, and not the OS

Comment: To anyone looking for how to fix the poor I/O performance, the solution is to [**cross-flash the firmware**](https://web.archive.org/web/20230427041420/https://fohdeesha.com/docs/perc.html) of the Dell PERC H310 from IR ("Integrated RAID") mode to IT ("Initiator Target") mode, effectively converting the HBA (host bus adapter) to an [LSI SAS 9211-8i](https://web.archive.org/web/20210209112812/https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12353333). The linked tutorial has easy-to-follow instructions on how to flash the IT firmware.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot to digest.

You're using ZFS, so there's a good chance that this is an issue with the 5TB disks in your pool and potentially your pool setup.

These may be 4k-sector disks, so some accommodations should be made in your ZFS setup to account for that.

Can you provide your `df -h`, `fdisk -l`, `zpool list`, `zpool status -v` and `zfs list` output?

Comment: Since the `txg_sync` message, I exported the only zpool (which wasn't even actively used at the time) in hopes that would help with the performance problem. The effect of taking down the zpool was negligible. Would you like me to reimport the zpool and provide you the outputs you requested anyway?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to. What filesystem are you using?

Comment: ext4 for `/`. There's ext2 for `/boot` and vfat for `/boot/efi`, but those probably don't matter. The sequential write benchmark that's killing the server isn't even on a filesystem―it's on the raw block device.

Answer (score 0):

I think your write cache is too big compared to your block device speeds. I would suggest following:

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 50000000
vm.dirty_bytes = 200000000
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 500
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 20
```

Never ever set both `*_bytes` and `*_ratio` because the last one that is set will win. In addition, some Linux kernel versions may have a bug where  setting `*_ratio` does not work as intended. I would suggest using `*_bytes` every time.

Unfortunately, the write cache settings are global as far as I know. As a result, throughput to your faster devices will suffer a bit when you need to reduce the global write cache size due to some slow device.

Comment: I've [already](https://serverfault.com/questions/776493/massive-performance-degradation-on-sustained-sequential-write#comment979771_776493) tried messing with the dirty memory settings and found that disabling the cache entirely works around the issue at a cost of 165× I/O performance degradation.  We know the Dell PERC H310 is part of the problem because [moving a hard drive directly to SATA makes the issue go away](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29625495#29625495) for that hard drive.  Perhaps the disk controller can't handle fast hard drives.